# Consider $X = \{(x_1,x_2 \dots x_n) | x_i \geq 0\}$, a subset of $R^n$. Is $A(X)$ a closed set when $A$ is a linear map from X to $R^m$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, optimization, linear-programming

While I was trying to prove Farkas' Lemma in Linear Programming (Pg. 19 of [these slides](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ewayne/kleinberg-tardos/pdf/LinearProgrammingII.pdf)), I came across the question posted in the title. If $A$ is invertible, then the result is straightforward. But what happens if $A$ is not? I'm also aware that there are linear transformations that are not closed (a [non-example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497944/a-linear-transform-of-a-closed-set-is-closed)). However, the set that I have here - $X$, is much "nicer" than the non-examples that I have seen.

Comment: The answer is in the affirmative, and has been discussed here [Linear transformation maps the first quadrant to a closed set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184132/linear-transformation-maps-the-first-quadrant-to-a-closed-set)

Comment: Aha, thank you. @Alex Ravsky's solution seems to be much cleaner though!

Comment: The answer has also been discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1831401/833910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two interpretations of the set $X$ in your question.

1)) The index $i$ in the definition of $X$ is fixed. A set $A(\Bbb R^n)$ is a linear subspace of $\Bbb R^m$, and is thus closed. Let  $e_i\in\Bbb R^n$ be the vector whose $i$-th coordinate equals $1$ and the other coordinates equals zero. Let $Y=\{(x_1,x_2 \dots x_n)\in\Bbb R^n| x_i=0\}$. If $A(e_i)\in A(Y)$ then $A(\Bbb R^n)=A(Y)=A(X)$, and so the latter set is closed. Otherwise pick any linear map $f:A(\Bbb R^n)\to \Bbb R$ such that $f(A(Y))=0$ and $f(A(e_i))=1$. Clearly, $f$ is continuous and $A(X)=f^{-1}([0,\infty))$ is a closed subspace of $A(\Bbb R^n)$.

2)) $X = \{(x_1,x_2 \dots x_n) | x_i \geq 0\mbox{ for all }i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\}$. Then $A(X)$ a cone generated by a finite set $\{A(e_1),\dots, A(e_n)\}$. By Weyl’s Theorem, $A(X)$ is polyhedral and therefore closed (see, for instance, [Paf, Theorem 1.8] and Definition 1.3 of a polyhedral cone).

*References*

[Paf] Andreas Paffenholz, *[Polyhedral Geometry and Linear Optimization. Summer Semester 2010](https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/%7Epaffenholz/daten/preprints/ln.pdf)*.

Comment: I understand why, for a fixed $i$, $A(X_i)$ is closed. But, we can't write $A(X) = \cap_iA(X_i)$ since we are not given that $A$ is injective right?

Comment: @KPN Oops, sorry. Thanks for your attention. I updated the answer to fix this issue, but, unfortunately, I do not have a  short proof for this case.

Comment: Could you define $X$ in  point (1) of your edit? Is $X=\{(x_1, \dots x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n | x_i \geq 0 \}$? Are you presenting two solutions? I'm not sure I understand the formatting. Also, the link seems to be broken.

Comment: @KPN I updated the answer. The link is OK.