# Using Farkas' Lemma to Prove Strong Duality

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

I've been trying to prove the Strong Duality Theorem following [these slides](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ewayne/kleinberg-tardos/pdf/LinearProgrammingII.pdf). In those slides, we start with proving Farkas' lemma, then a corollary followed by the proof of the Strong Duality Theorem. To prove Farkas' lemma, I first proved that $\{A(x)|x \in X_n\}$ where $X_j = \{x=(x_1,x_2 \dots x_j) \in \mathbb{R}^j | x_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } 1\leq i \leq j\}$ and $A \in M(m,n)$, is a closed, convex set. This was deceptively hard and has been discussed in [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831401/how-do-you-prove-that-ax-mid-x-geq-0-is-closed) [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184132/linear-transformation-maps-the-first-quadrant-to-a-closed-set). Using this I managed to prove the following:
Let $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Exactly one of these two linear programs have a solution:
\begin{align}
        Ax&=b\\
        x &\in X_n \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{align}
        (A^Ty) &\in X_n\\
        \langle b,y \rangle &< 0 \nonumber\\
        y &\in \mathbb{R}^m
\end{align}
This is Farkas' lemma. I also managed to prove this "corollary". I put it in quotes because I could not use the Farkas' lemma directly to get the result. The corollary is as follows: Let $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Exactly one of these two linear programs have a solution:
\begin{align}
        Ax+s&=b\\
        x &\in X_n \nonumber\\
        s &\in X_m \nonumber
 \end{align}
\begin{align}
        A^Ty &\in X_n \nonumber\\
        \langle b,y \rangle &< 0 \\
        y &\in X_m \nonumber
 \end{align}

The final step of this puzzle, which directly proves the Strong Duality Theorem is what I am trying to solve. This is what I am trying to prove now: For any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$, and $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$, prove that exactly one of these two linear programs have a solution:
\begin{align}
        Ax+s&=b\\
        \langle c,x \rangle &\leq \alpha \nonumber\\
        x &\in X_n \nonumber\\
        s &\in X_m \nonumber
 \end{align}
\begin{align}
         \langle b,y \rangle + \alpha z&< 0 \\
        A^Ty + cz&\in X_n \nonumber\\
        y &\in X_m \nonumber\\
        z &\in \mathbb{R}_+ \nonumber 
 \end{align}
Here are my questions:

- Is there a way to prove Farkas' corollary using Farkas' lemma?
- How do I prove the last step from Farkas' corollary?

Comment: Here's another good thread about the fact that $\{Ax \mid x \geq 0 \}$ is a closed set: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831401/how-do-you-prove-that-ax-mid-x-geq-0-is-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first system of the last alternative is
$$
Ax+s = b, \ \langle c,x\rangle \le \alpha, \ x\ge 0, \ s \ge0.
$$
Introducting a slack variable $t\ge 0$, this can be written as
$$
\pmatrix{A& I & 0 \\ c^T&0 & 1} \pmatrix{ x \\ s \\ t} = \pmatrix {b \\ \alpha }
$$
with $x\ge0,s\ge0,t\ge0$. By Farkas Lemma, either this system or the following one is solvable:
$$
\pmatrix{A^T & c\\  I & 0 \\ 0 & 1} \pmatrix{y \\ z} \ge 0
$$
$$
b^Ty + \alpha z < 0,
$$
which is the second alternative in the last system.

Comment: From Farkas' corollary, I get that one of $(A \, I) \cdot (x \, s)^T = b$ or $(A^T \, I)^T \cdot y \geq 0$, $b^Ty<0$ is solvable. How do I extend that to include the extra variables - $\alpha$, $z$?

Comment: I applied the Farkas Lemma (instead of the corollary). Also $\alpha$ is not a variable. You have to introduce extra variables to be able to apply it.

Comment: @daw: Can you clarify how knowing that the first system in $x$ is consistent (which implies that the second in $y$ is inconsistent) shows strong duality? I thought we would like to show $"\forall\alpha:c^\top x \leq \alpha \implies b^\top y \leq \alpha" \iff c^\top x \geq b^\top y$