# Slater's condition for closedness of the linear image of a closed convex cone

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators

I would like to understand what is known as *Slater's condition* for the closedness of the linear image of a closed, convex cone.

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $W=\mathbb{R}^m$ (i.e. finite dimensional real inner product spaces), let $A:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear map, and let $K\subseteq V$ be a closed convex cone.

First some notation:

- The *dual cone* of $K$ is the set
  $$
      K^* = \{v\in V \,:\, \langle  v,x\rangle \geq 0\}.
   $$
- The *adjoint* map of $A$ is the unique linear map $A^*:W\rightarrow V$ such that $\langle A x,y\rangle = \langle x, A^* y\rangle$ for all $x,y$.
- The *interior* of $K^*$ is denoted $\mathrm{int}(K^*)$ and can be defined as follows: For $v\in\mathrm{int}(K^*)$ and $x\in K$, if $\langle v,x\rangle = 0$ then $x=0$.
- The image of $K$ under $A$ will be denoted 
  $$
   A(K) = \{Ax \,:\, x\in K\}.
  $$

What I would like to prove is the following:

**Theorem.** Suppose there exists a $y\in W$ such that $A^*y\in\mathrm{int}(K^*)$. Then $A(K)$ is closed.

Here is my attempt to prove:

Let $\{y_i\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $A(K)$, and let $\overline{y}\in W$ such that $y_i\rightarrow \overline{y}$. (We want to show that $\overline{y}\in A(K)$ to show that $A(K)$ is closed.) Since $y_i\in A(K)$, we can find $x_i\in K$ such that $Ax_i=y_i$. Since $\{y_i\}$ is Cauchy, it is bounded so there exists a $c\geq 0$ such that 
$$
\langle A^*y,x_i\rangle = \langle y,y_i\rangle \leq c
$$
for all $i$.  We can assume without loss of generality that each $y_i\neq 0$, then each $x_i$ also satisfies
$$
0<\langle A^*y,x_i\rangle 
$$
since $x_i\in K$ and we assume $A^*y\in\mathrm{int}(K^*)$. Thus, each $x_i$ satisfies
$$
0<\langle A^*y,x_i\rangle \leq c.
$$
Somehow this implies that the sequence $\{x_i\}$ must be bounded?  **This is what I do not understand** and I might be missing something.

Finally, since $\{x_i\}$ is a bounded sequence in a closed $K$, it has an accumulation point $x$ which satisfies $Ax=\overline{y}$.

All that I do not understand is how to show that $\{x_i\}$ is bounded. Any help is appreciated.

(Note: The existence of $y$ such that $A^*y\in\mathrm{int}(K^*)$ is known as *Slater's condition*).

Comment: Essentially, what I want is to prove Proposition 1.3 on page 7 of  [these notes](https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande314/314Chap1and2.pdf) (which is given there as an exercise).

Comment: Do you know how this connects to what is normally called Slater's​ condition in convex optimization?

Comment: Can this result be used to prove that $\{Ax \mid x\geq 0\}$ is closed? (Some proofs of this fact are given here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831401/how-do-you-prove-that-ax-mid-x-geq-0-is-closed/2316689#2316689 )

Comment: Something you call here relative interior is not actually relative interior of $K^*$. They don't coincide! 

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_interior  for definition of  **relint**

Comment: @Ashkan. You're right. I suppose I really just mean the true interior, not the relative interior. The interior of the dual cone does in fact coincide with the set I describe.

Comment: @littleO It is related, but I'm not sure how. Maybe someone else knows? Regarding your second question, I think the answer is no. The condition in this question is a sufficient condition for A(K) to be closed, but not a necessary one.

Comment: In fact, as a counter example, consider $A=\left(\begin{array}{ll}1&-1 \end{array}\right)$ from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The image of the positive orthant under $A$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$ (which is closed), but Slater's condition doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. It appears to be a fairly standard argument in duality theorems for conic programming.

---

Suppose instead that $\{x_i\}$ is unbounded. We will derive a contradiction.

Define the sequence $\tilde x_i = \frac{x_i}{\lVert x_i\rVert}$, which is in $K$. It is clearly bounded so it converges (or at least has a convergent subsequence) $\tilde x_i \rightarrow\tilde x $ to some $\tilde x\in K$ and $\tilde x \neq 0$. Hence
$$
0<\langle A^*y, \tilde x_i \rangle\leq \frac{1}{\lVert x_i\rVert}c
$$
for all $\tilde x_i$. Since $\{x_i\}$ is unbounded, it follows that $\langle A^*y, \tilde x_i \rangle\rightarrow 0$. Hence
$$
\langle A^*y, \tilde x \rangle = \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\langle A^*y, \tilde x_i \rangle =0.
$$
But $A^*y\in\mathrm{int}(K^*)$ implies that $\tilde x=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: I can see only how to prove what you said when we are actually looking for $\text{int}(K^{*})$, but not $\text{relint} (K*)$. See PROPOSITION 1.1.4. of the book https://global.oup.com/academic/product/analysis-on-symmetric-cones-9780198534778?cc=us&lang=en&

Comment: His answer does not hold when $\text{int} (K^{*})$ is substituted by $\text{relint} (K^*)$. For the relint version, I recommend following the article "On the closedness of the linear image of a closed convex cone." Directly finding yourself proof is not something one should pursue due to its difficulty. Instead, the article I recommended would enlighten your ideas even more than finding a proof by yourself. Sometimes, we need to stand on the shoulders of giants